# How to use a dynamically created column in a WHERE clause

Tags: sql, concatenation, where-clause, sql-like

I created a table column called name cause the firstname and the lastname are stored in two separate columns. To solve the problem I use `CONCAT` in the `SELECT` statement. However if I want to search for a specific value inside the name column SQL returns the error:

> Unknown column 'name' in 'where clause'

Is it possible to search in a dynamically created column in a `SELECT` statement?

```
SELECT 
    u.ID AS id,
    CONCAT(umFirstName.meta_value, " ", umLastName.meta_value) AS name,
    u.user_email AS email,
    umChatStatus.meta_value AS chatStatus,
    umCallStatus.meta_value AS callStatus,
    umRef.meta_value AS reference
FROM 
    wp_users AS u
LEFT JOIN 
    wp_usermeta AS um ON u.ID = um.user_id
LEFT JOIN 
    wp_usermeta AS umFirstName ON u.ID = umFirstName.user_id 
                               AND umFirstName.meta_key = "_ctbFirstName"
LEFT JOIN 
    wp_usermeta AS umLastName ON u.ID = umLastName.user_id 
                              AND umLastName.meta_key = "_ctbLastName"
LEFT JOIN 
    wp_usermeta AS umChatStatus ON u.ID = umChatStatus.user_id 
                                AND umChatStatus.meta_key = "_ctbChatSessionStatus"
LEFT JOIN 
    wp_usermeta AS umCallStatus ON u.ID = umCallStatus.user_id 
                                AND umCallStatus.meta_key = "_ctbCallSessionStatus" 
LEFT JOIN 
    wp_usermeta AS umRef ON u.ID = umRef.user_id 
                         AND umRef.meta_key = "_ctbRef"
WHERE 
    um.meta_key = "wp_capabilities"
    AND um.meta_value IN ('a:1:{s:8:"employee ";b:1;}') 
    AND u.id LIKE '%%'
     OR name LIKE '%%'
     OR u.user_email LIKE '%%'
     OR umChatStatus.meta_value LIKE '%%'
     OR umCallStatus.meta_value LIKE '%%'
     OR umRef.meta_value LIKE'%%'
ORDER BY 
    id DESC
LIMIT 0, 20
```

*UPDATE*

Got it working like it should. Thanks to Caius Jard metioning to -always use parentheses- in a AND and OR mix. For someone that is interested in the solution.

[image: added parentheses for the second AND and CONCAT() for the search result]

Comment: You should use fullText search or create a view of your query and on that view apply where clause 
for fullText search you can refer https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mysql-full-text-search-functions.php

Comment: When you mix AND and OR in a where clause, always, always use parentheses to clearly explain to the db and other developers what you want. `(name = john AND age = 20) or city = chicago` is very different to `name = john and (age = 20 or city = chicago)` - if we leave off the parens, and write `name = john and age = 20 or city = chicago` do you know for sure which of the earlier two the db will do?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/operator-precedence.html Here's a list of operators, and = LIKE IN etc all have precedence, so the comparisons evaluate first. That means we can think of the clause as something like `true` AND `true` OR `false` OR `true`... and evaluate that to see what happens. AND has precedence over OR, so all of the AND conditions will operate as a unit.  So consider two situations: `false` OR `false` will evaluate to false. But `false` OR `true` evaluates to true.  So in this WHERE any single OR can make the whole clause `true`. Parenthesize those conditions.

Answer (score 2):

SQL queries are evaluated in the following order (just the blocks you've used):

```
FROM (including joins)
WHERE
SELECT
ORDER BY
```

This means that something you create in the SELECT, like `CONCAT(Firstname, ' ', LastName)` simply doesn't exist at the time the WHERE is evaluated

You have a couple of options:

- Use `CONCAT(Firstname, ' ', LastName)` in the WHERE clause too

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(Firstname, ' ', LastName) AS N
FROM
  person
WHERE
  CONCAT(Firstname, ' ', LastName) = 'John smith'
```

- Turn the whole query into a sub query and use the thing you created in the outer

```
SELECT 
  x.N
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      CONCAT(Firstname, ' ', LastName) AS N
    FROM
      person
  ) x
WHERE 
  x.N = 'John smith'
```

This form can also be written as:

```
WITH x AS
  (
    SELECT
      CONCAT(Firstname, ' ', LastName) AS N
    FROM
      person
  ) 

SELECT x.N
FROM x
WHERE x.N = 'John smith'
```

These latter forms are useful when you want to use it multiple times and don't want to keep repeating some massive calculation:

```
WITH x AS
  (
    SELECT
      SUM(Points) / DATEDIFF(day, MIN(GameStart), MAX(GameEnd)) as PointsPerDay
    FROM
      Games
    GROUP BY PlayerId
  ) 

SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN PointsPerDay < 100 THEN 'Newbie'
    WHEN PointsPerDay < 200 THEN 'Seasoned'
    WHEN PointsPerDay < 300 THEN 'Advanced'
    ELSE 'Pro'
  END as Grading
FROM x
```

To have to keep repeating a calculation in order to do it all in one query is a bit ugly:

```
SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN SUM(Points) / DATEDIFF(day, MIN(GameStart), MAX(GameEnd)) < 100 THEN 'Newbie'
    WHEN SUM(Points) / DATEDIFF(day, MIN(GameStart), MAX(GameEnd)) < 200 THEN 'Seasoned'
    WHEN SUM(Points) / DATEDIFF(day, MIN(GameStart), MAX(GameEnd)) < 300 THEN 'Advanced'
    ELSE 'Pro'
  END as Grading
FROM 
  Games
GROUP BY PlayerId
```

And indeed because a GROUP BY is evaluated after a WHERE, if you want to use the result of a group by in a where you must do it as a "sub query that groups"/"outer query that wheres" pair

Comment: I have a feeling those booleans in the where clause are going to trip him up too.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly compare the concatenated value in the where clause like so:
`CONCAT(umFirstName.meta_value, " ", umLastName.meta_value) LIKE '%abc%'`

```sql
SELECT 
u.ID                                                      AS id,
CONCAT(umFirstName.meta_value, " ", umLastName.meta_value) AS name,
u.user_email                                              AS email,
umChatStatus.meta_value                                   AS chatStatus,
umCallStatus.meta_value                                   AS callStatus,
umRef.meta_value                                          AS reference
FROM wp_users AS u
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta AS um ON u.ID = um.user_id
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta AS umFirstName ON u.ID = umFirstName.user_id AND 
umFirstName.meta_key = "_ctbFirstName"
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta AS umLastName ON u.ID = umLastName.user_id AND 
umLastName.meta_key = "_ctbLastName"
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta AS umChatStatus
ON u.ID = umChatStatus.user_id AND umChatStatus.meta_key = "_ctbChatSessionStatus"
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta AS umCallStatus
ON u.ID = umCallStatus.user_id AND umCallStatus.meta_key = "_ctbCallSessionStatus" 
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta AS umRef ON u.ID = umRef.user_id AND umRef.meta_key = "_ctbRef"
WHERE um.meta_key = "wp_capabilities"
AND um.meta_value IN ('a:1:{s:8:"employee ";b:1;}') 
AND u.id LIKE '%%'
OR CONCAT(umFirstName.meta_value, " ", umLastName.meta_value) LIKE '%%'
OR u.user_email LIKE '%%'
OR umChatStatus.meta_value LIKE '%%'
OR umCallStatus.meta_value LIKE '%%'
OR umRef.meta_value LIKE'%%'
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 0, 20
```